# OSX Mavericks cycle through active buttons

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcuts

I have moved to OSX from a while now and something that really bugs me is that I can't cycle through the buttons of an app.

For instance when I try to close an application and it asks me wether I want to save the file or not I cant just hit tab and select don't save.

Does someone know how I can add a shortcut like that or is there a pre-built functionality I can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Launch System Preferences from the  Apple menu
2. Click on the “Keyboards” preference panel
3. Select the “Shortcuts” tab (sometimes called “Keyboard Shortcuts” in older versions of OS X)
4. Look near the bottom of the window for a mention of “Full Keyboard Access: In windows and dialogs, press Tab to move keyboard focus between:” and click to select the radio button next to “All controls”*
5. Close System Preferences

See also:

http://lmgtfy.com/?q=select+button+with+tab+key+mac+osx

Comment: ...after that, use the tab key to cycle through the buttons of a dialog box, and hit the spacebar to actually hit that button.